# jquery - background-image - Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, mime

I am loading background images for a set of divs with the following method in jquery (within the $(document).ready(function(){}):

```
$('.outD').each(function(){
    var inD = $(this).children().eq(0);
    /* EACH INNER DIV HAS AN INPUT ELEMENT WHOSE NAME MATCHES THE 
    BACKGROUND-IMAGE's NAME */
    /* SO I GATHER THE PORTION OF THE INPUT NAME TO BE USED IN THE 
    BACKGROUND-IMAGE URL */
    var imgName = inD.find('input[name="usr_min"]').next().attr('name').split('_');
    /* THEN I CREATE THE URL STRING TO BE INSERTED INTO THE CSS LINE BELOW */
    var backImg = "url('imgs/" + imgName[0] + ".png')";
    /* ALL THE ABOVE IS WORKING FINE AS I GET THE PROPER URL STRING ALERTED BELOW */ 
    alert(backImg);
    /* BUT WHEN I CALL THE FOLLOWING LINE TO ACTUALLY APPLY THE BACKGROUND IMAGE
    TO EACH OF THE $('.outD') DIVS LISTED, ONLY THE FIRST DIV GETS THE PROPER
    BACKGROUND IMAGE APPLIED */
    $(this).css("background-image",  backImg);
});
```

For the remainder of the $('.outD') divs I receive "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html in chrome debug and no image seems to get loaded as the backgrounds remain white.

Any ideas as to why setting the background image will only work for the first div but returns the error listed above for all remaining divs?

Here is the html of the affected div:

```
<div class="outD">
    <div class="inD1">
        <img src="./sHandle.png" style="width: 16px; height: 24px;" alt="">
        <img src="../sBack.png" alt="">
        <input type="hidden" name="usr_min" value="<?php echo minVal ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="pChange_Min" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="pChange_index" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="isPercent" value="true">
    </div>
    <div class="inD2">
        <img src="./sHandle.png" style="width: 16px; height: 24px;" alt="">
        <img src="../sBack.png" alt="">
        <input type="hidden" name="usr_max" value="<?php echo maxVal; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="pChange_Max" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Again, each of the above div's have a different input name for the input element immediately following the "usr_min" input element.  Each image to be loaded as a background in the outD div is titled after this input element's name.  I.e. in this case, the image url being called, and alerted in the alert(imgName); statement above is:

```
imgs/pChange.png
```

As I said before, this works for the first div but not for the remainder of divs which are identical in layout.

Comment: Could you also show the html code of your element with class `.outD` please?

Comment: @Dim13i posted... Help at all?

Comment: Found the problem, each image had a suffix of qrtly when they were supposed to have the suffix of qtrly.  Spelling mistake when naming images.. I apologize for the mis-post.  To admins, this posting can now be removed/locked.